# Visio dragDrop shape position not updated

Tags: vba, visio

In this guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767482.aspx , I am able to get a event trigger when I drag and drop my shapes. But the problem is the shape position is not updated to the drop position when I received this event trigger. My question is how do I get a updated position of the shape after I drop the it to perform some overlap check on the shape with other shapes in Visio?

```
Dim strMessage As String

'Find out which event and event extension fired
Select Case nEventCode
    Case visEvtCodeMouseMove
        Dim strInfo As String
        If (pSubjectObj.DragState = visMouseMoveDragStatesDrop) Then
            strMessage = "MouseMove - dragDrop"

            'Shape position is not updated to drop position here

        End If
    Case Else
        strMessage = "Other (" & nEventCode & ")"
End Select

 'Display the event name and the event code
If (Len(strMessage)) Then
    Debug.Print strMessage
End If
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

In your first `If` statement, the subject object should be a `MouseEvent` object which has x and y properties (note in inches).  You can then use those to search for any shapes that the target shape has been dropped on:

```
Dim evtMouse As Visio.MouseEvent
Dim selSearchShapes As Visio.Selection
...
Set evtMouse = pSubjectObj

Set selSearchShapes = evtMouse.Application.ActivePage.SpatialSearch(evtMouse.x, _
  evtMouse.y, _
  Visio.VisSpatialRelationCodes.visSpatialContainedIn, _
  0, _
  Visio.VisSpatialRelationFlags.visSpatialFrontToBack)

Debug.Print "Spatial search found: " & selSearchShapes.Count

If selSearchShapes.Count > 0 Then
  Debug.Print "Spatial search - top shape: " & selSearchShapes(1).NameID
End If
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The evtMouse.x and evtMouse .y seems to always be a little off by some inches from the drop position of my selected shape.I tried getting the selected shape using ActiveWindow.Selection(1), when I extract the coordinates by doing : 
Selectedshp.Cells("PinX").ResultIU
it seems to give me a value that is a little bit offset from the orginal drop position of the shape. I can't seem to get the exact coordinate of the shape after I drop it.

Comment: You might find that snapping alters the final position of the dropped shape from the actual mouse position and that this effect will be magnified or more evident the further out the zoom level.